# When a callback returns a Deferred in Twisted

Tags: twisted, deferred

This is an example from 'Twisted Network Programming Essential':

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.web.client import Agent

import sys

from random import random

class ResourcePrinter(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, finished):
        self.finished = finished

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print data

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.finished.callback(None)

def printResource(response):
    # Nothing added to this 'finished'
    finished = Deferred()
    response.deliverBody(ResourcePrinter(finished))
    return finished

def printError(failure):
    print >>sys.stderr, failure

def stop(result):
    reactor.stop()

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'Usage'
    exit(1)

agent = Agent(reactor)
d = agent.request('GET', sys.argv[1])
d.addCallbacks(printResource, printError)
d.addBoth(stop)

reactor.run()
```

But since it never calls `addCallback()` on `finished` in `printResource()`, why would `stop()` finally be called in `connectionLost()`?

Answer (score 2):

This is using a feature called "chaining", documented at http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html#auto13.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it does not need to add any more callback. It s added already hear:

```
self.finished.callback(None)
```

So, lets look at more careful. Code pointer reaches hear:

```
d.addCallbacks(printResource, printError)
```

When you look at printResource code block, it returns a **deferred** as return value. So, until this deferred object obtain its result, data delivery will go on til get connection lost event (catched by Protocol overrided method) and the last step or callback caused finished(deferred) object, give that its result.

```
Main deferred -> add callback -> callback by coming responses-> |
                                                                |
                                                                 -> new deferred -> Receiving data ... til con lost -> add callaback (get result directly)|
                                                                                                                                                          |-> add last callback > stop
```

The key point is, when a return value is a deferred, until getting result of this deferred object, main flow will not continue.